# Глаголы «отличать» и «различать». Переходность

Tags: глаголы

Помогите определить переходность.

**Я не знаю, как отличить яблоко от груши. (переходный)**

**Я не знаю, как различать яблоки и груши. (?)**

Различать — переходный или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Из Викисловаря

> раз-ли-ча́ть Глагол, несовершенный вид, **переходный**, тип спряжения по классификации А. Зализняка — 1a

Из Википедии

> Перехо́дный глаго́л (лат. verbum transitivum) — глагол, вступающий в сочетание с существительным в винительном падеже без предлога в значении прямого объекта действия

Для того, чтобы проверить переходный глагол или нет, достаточно посмотреть как он взаимодействует с объектами. За переходным глаголом следует объект в винительном падеже (кого? что?) без предлога

Примеры:

- отличить (<strike>кого?</strike> что?) яблоко от груши (переходный)
- различать (<strike>кого?</strike> что?) яблоки и груши (переходный)
- различать (<strike>кого?</strike> что?) цвета (переходный)
- различать (кого? <strike>что?</strike>) людей и животных (переходный)

Примеры непереходных глаголов:

- Я иду в театр (есть предлог, значит непереходный)
- Я весь день стучал молотком (отвечает на вопрос чем?, творительный падеж, непереходный)

Comment: А если "Я весь день стучал по молотку"? Что за падеж и переходный ли СТУЧАЛ?

Comment: Дательный падеж (кому? чему?), непереходный

Comment: А как вы вывели вопрос (кому? чему?) из "по молотку"?

Comment: Молоток это неодушевленное существительное мужского рода, 2-го склонения, единственного числа. По падежам:
Им. : молоток
Р. : молотка
Д. : молотку
В. : молоток
Тв. : молотком
Пр. : молотке

Comment: ОК. И что? Это как-то определяет вопрос? Допустим "Я весь день стучал по девочке". Тут уже другой вопрос? И другой падеж?

Comment: Вопрос "по кому?", падеж тот же

Comment: То есть "Я был в лесу" и "Я вышел из лесу". "Лесу" - дательный?

Comment: Я был (в чём?) в лесу (предложный падеж). Я вышел (из чего?) из лесА (родительный падеж)

Comment: Но даже если использовать устаревшую форму "лесу", за предлогом из всегда идёт глагол родительного падежа

Comment: А после предлога по всегда идёт дательный падеж

Comment: Дополнительный вопрос: Я весь день стучал по молотку. День – это В.п. без предлога. Стучал – переходный глагол?

Comment: @Sharon, я написал "За переходным глаголом следует объект в винительном падеже (кого? что?) **без предлога**", и "Я иду в театр (**есть предлог**, значит непереходный)". Вы ознакомились с моим ответом, прежде чем писать к нему комментарии?

Comment: Я обратила внимание на комментарии, где очень долго обсуждались варианты глаголов с предлогами.  А это просто дополнительные вопросы по теме.   (1) Почему у вас объект следует за глаголом? Объект может стоять и перед глаголом, например: Билеты купили. (2) Весь день  работали.  Можете объяснить, почему  здесь используется форма В.п., а глагол непереходный.

Comment: @Sharon, Не могу. Вы победили. Я вынужден признать, что вам нет равных. Я удаляюсь

Comment: @Tape Пожалуйста, останьтесь.  Нам очень не хватает  участников, которые отвечают на вопросы, а не только их задают.  Вообще-то я люблю новых людей. ОК?

Comment: @Tape  У вас хороший ответ (правда, почему-то точек нигде нет), я проголосовал за него.

Comment: Я тоже за него проголосовала.